# Simplifying my code

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to simplify the following jQuery code? Thanks a lot.

```
$("#letter1").click(function () {
    clickLetter(1, $(this));
});
$("#letter2").click(function () {
    clickLetter(2, $(this));
});
$("#letter3").click(function () {
    clickLetter(3, $(this));
});
$("#letter4").click(function () {
    clickLetter(4, $(this));
});
```

Sorry I forgot to mention that there were 26 letters, so the last item would be

```
$("#letter26").click(function () {
    clickLetter(26, $(this));
});
```

I was trying to avoid hard-coding. Thank you.

Comment: yes, read about [for statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)

Comment: @Lashane http://w3fools.com -- don't link to W3Schools

Comment: @Lashane Read the site i linked to. W3Schools often has bad or obsolete information.

Comment: @Scimonster So has Wikipedia, is there anything wrong with the page Lashane linked to?

Comment: @ZippyV `document.write` is not best practice; a `for` loop does not have to loop "a number of times"; the middle part of a `for` loop is an expression, not a statement; and there is also bad grammar.

Comment: @ZippyV Also, the difference is that anyone can update Wikipedia, while that is not the case with W3Schools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to loop, and you don't even have to hardcode the number of elements, you can do this :

```
$("[id^=letter]").click(function () {
    clickLetter(+this.id.slice('letter'.length), $(this));
});
```

Three parts :

- select elements whose id starts with "letter" using the [starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
- get the part of the id after "letter" (the number part)
- convert this number part, which is a string, to a real number

Comment: Hello. Not 100% sure but it looks like the click event would fire twice. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: I don't think the problem is here. You're probably doing the binding twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
[1,2,3,4].forEach(function(i){
    $("#letter"+i).click(function () {
        clickLetter(i, $(this));
   });
});
```

Comment: Hardcoding the number of elements isn't really clean, though.

Comment: @dystroy true, but it does fulfill simplifying.